# c# Some elements not show at the list intersection

Tags: c#, list, intersect

I am trying to get the common elementes of two lists. The example is as follows:

```
var control = "F, H, S, W".Split(',').ToList();
var drives = new List<string> {"C", "D", "E", "F", "H" };
var common = drives.Intersect(control).ToList();
common.ForEach(x =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(x);
});
```

Normally `F` and `H` should return here, but only `F` returns. I don't make any sense.

Comment: You're only splitting on `','`, so all of your entries after the first have a leading space.  Try splitting on "comma space", or eliminate the spaces from your string.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I can't believe I ignored something so simple. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

When you split the string `"F, H, S, W"` you get the Array `[ "F", " H", " S", " W" ]`. Because there are spaces after each comma, they are in the split array aswell. Therefore, if you compare `"H"` to `" H"` it's false because of the spaces. You can fix this issue by calling the `.Trim()` function on each element of the split list to remove all leading and ending spaces.

```cs
var control = "F, H, S, W".Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
var drives = new List<string> { "C", "D", "E", "F", "H" };
var common = drives.Intersect(control).ToList();
common.ForEach(x =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(x);
});
```

Comment: @TimRoberts didn't know how to reply here?